# ServerManager.GetAdministrationConfiguration is empty on IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, iis, servermanager

I want to manage IIS (versions 7-10) by using C# [ServerManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager?view=iis-dotnet) сlass.

Locally `GetAdministrationConfiguration` method returns 1 section group and 2 sections in administration config (see code below).

But on remote server there are 0 section groups and 0 sections.

Source code (need to add `Microsoft.Web.Administration` in "Extensions" references of C# project):

```cs
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var iisManager = new ServerManager())
            {
                var c = iisManager.GetAdministrationConfiguration();

                Console.WriteLine(c.RootSectionGroup.SectionGroups.Count);
                Console.WriteLine(c.RootSectionGroup.Sections.Count);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

- Local machine: Win10, IIS 10.0, .NET framework 4.7.1.
- Remote server #1: Win2008R2, IIS 7.5, .NET framework 4.7.2.
- Remote server #2: Win7, IIS 7.5, .NET framework 4.5.2.

On all machines `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\administration.config` is avaliable and contains all needed sections.

How to get administration configuration of IIS on remote servers?

Comment: If your goal is to "manage IIS", then `administration.config` can be safely ignored, as it is the configuration for IIS Manager (which has little to do with the sites/applications).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Based on [MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c54f8368-035e-478e-b988-b180a3c7e3da/file-not-found-for-existing-file-in-system32-directory?forum=csharpgeneral) I unchecked "Prefer 32-bit" in C# project properties and configuration is received now.